# Create keyboard shortcut to regionate method

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Can I in Visual Studio create keyboard shortcut to regionate method and auto-document it with GhostDoc?

From this:

```csh
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnInit(e);
}
```

I want make this:

```csh
#region protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
/// <summary>
/// Raises the <see cref="E:Init"/> event.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{           
   base.OnInit(e);
} 
#endregion
```

Comment: I am wondering the same thing... especially the first part, regionating selected code

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I am not sure about the GhostDoc auto documentation, but to regionate selected text you can use the "surround with" function in Visual Studio.

Select a portion of code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>. This brings up the "surround with" context menu. Select "region" in the menu, type in your region name and you're all set.

This function can be used for a bunch of other stuff as well. If, for, while and try statements and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Type three slashes to auto-generate the documentation